# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs', I am getting this error while I am trying to scrape images from the url. How can I fix it?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import bs4
import requests
url ="https://www.passiton.com/inspirational-quotes?page=2"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content)
article_element = soup.findAll('img')

for i, article in enumerate(article_element):
with open('inspiration{}.jpg'.format(i),'wb') as file:
    img_url = article.img.attrs['src']
    response = requests.get(img_url)

    file.write(response.content)
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs', I am getting this error while trying to scrapping images from the url. How can I fix it? Please help me with this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve with `article.img.attrs['src']`. You can just use `article[src]` to get the relative image URL in your example. Combine this with the main URL, and you should be able to get the images. This should fix your error:

```py
import bs4
import requests
main_url = "https://www.passiton.com/"
url ="https://www.passiton.com/inspirational-quotes?page=2"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content)
article_element = soup.findAll('img')

for i, article in enumerate(article_element):
with open('inspiration.jpg','wb') as file:
    img_url = main_url+article['src']
    response = requests.get(img_url)
    file.write(response.content)
```

Comment: Only some images are visible but maximum images looks like they are corrupted when I am using 'url' instead of 'main_url' in the last third line of the code.
Also I used 'inspiration{}.jpg'.format(i),'wb')

Comment: Random guess: If some images come out good, it is probably because you try to save them as a `.jpg`, while they are probably a different filetype. Have you tried different file types to save them?

Comment: Sorry, If I am using url instead of main_url, no images are showing looks like corrupted.

Comment: you shouldn't use url for fetching the images. That is because an image is stored at `https://www.passiton.com/assets/path/to/image`. When you use `article['src']`, you are only getting the `assets/path/to/image` part of the link, so you should paste `https://www.passiton.com/` in front of it. If you use `https://www.passiton.com/inspirational...`, that will break the link to your image.

Comment: if i am extracting one image at a time, it is working for 'url'

Answer (score 0):

to avoid crash if no key in dict, use

```
dict.get('key')  # returns value or None
```

instead of

```
dict['key']  # returns value or crash
```